# Change date format in order to find difference in Time in Neo4j 3.2.5

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am working on a code in Neo4j and want to find out the difference between two time columns. The date time is in format `20130508 19:14:56.913`. 
I also tried using APOC function, but I am getting the error that it is Unknown function. Could anyone please help me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) function `apoc.date.parse`. The function signature is:

```
apoc.date.parse(date, targetTimeUnit, format)
```

`date` should be a string representing the date you are converting to the specified `targetTimeUnit` (`ms` for target milliseconds, in the example). The `date` should be in the specified `format`, indicated by the third parameter.

Take a look in this example:

```
WITH apoc.date.parse('20130508 19:14:56.913','ms','yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.ms') AS initialTime,
    apoc.date.parse('20130508 20:14:56.913','ms','yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.ms') AS finalTime
RETURN finalTime - initialTime as difference
```

The output will be:

```
╒════════════╕
│"difference"│
╞════════════╡
│3600000     │
└────────────┘
```

That is: a difference of 3600000 milliseconds between the two dates.

Comment: I tried this, I got this error: Unknown function 'apoc.date.parse'

Comment: @Shefali so you have a problem in your APOC installation.

Comment: How should APOC be installed?

Comment: @Shefali you can found installation instructions in [this link](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_installation). Basically you need download the jar file and put it into the Neo4j's `/plugins` directory. Remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the version compatibility matrix in the link.